# Команда стрельбы из лука

Tags: терминология

Поскольку справка до сих не говорит, можно ли, счёл, что можно задать такой вопрос. Он где-то посередине между языком и историей.

Существует ли в русском языке команда (приказ) для стрельбы из лука? Командовать "огонь" или "пли" совершенно неверно. В английском более-менее ясно - "draw" и "loose", хотя по недоразумению иногда используется "fire" в фильмах и книгах. Но вот в русском языке мне не удалось найти достоверных следов, утверждающих или опровергающих, что такая команда была, пусть даже это слово "стреляй". Я даже не смог найти, что используется сейчас для соревнований и прочего, если используется. У меня есть мнение, что поскольку практики залповой стрельбы из лука на Руси в отличии от Англии не было, то возможно, что и устоявшейся команды для этого действия не было.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос. Залповой стрельбы из лука на Руси не практиковали. Основой русской средневековой армии были пешие копейщики и конная дружина с мечами и палицами. Луки использовали прежде всего передовые полки застрельщиков, но залповую стрельбу не применяли и они.

Сейчас команду о стрельбе из лука можно дать любую. Не вижу ничего зазорного и во фразе "пли", так как хоть это слово и происходит от "пали" (поджигай фитиль), сегодня уже потеряло конкретную привязку к огнестрельному оружию.

Comment: Я лишь предполагал. Хотелось подтверждения. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: *Луки использовали прежде всего передовые полки застрельщиков, но залповую* - Марк Из, но ведь речь не обязательно о залповой идет. При осаде, например, лучники ведь применялись? Причем и осаждаемыми, и осаждавшими. Значит, какая-то команда была. Другое дело, что она не была скорее всего привязана конкретно к лучникам. Ну мог же там князь скомандовать какому верному опричнику с луком "Давай!"?!

Comment: @behemothus Команду конечно отдать мог, скорее всего всего "стреляй", но без залповой стрельбы из лука необходимости в отделении команд "стреляй" от "пли" не было, поэтому сейчас обе можно применить к любому оружию дальнего боя.

Comment: Это понятно. Ок, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

На соревнованиях сигнал о начале и окончании лимита времени подается свистком или другим звуковым устройством. Остальное - визуально. В специальной команде необходимости нет.

Думаю, что её и раньше не было.

А вообще есть универсальное "пошел", годящееся хоть для битвы на мечах, хоть для бальных танцев, хоть для соревнований по выпечке блинов на лопате.

Answer (score 1):

Подходящая цитата:

> На дворе лучники практиковались в стрельбе по мишеням, и слышались
> команды: «Наложи – натяни – пускай».

Answer (score 0):

"Бей".  "Тост на охоте должен быть краткий, как команда, как выстрел, иначе времени на отдых не останется!" (с) Особенности национальной охоты.

> Бить бити (2) 1. Убивать (добычу): О! Далече заиде соколъ, птиць бья,
> къ морю. 19 20. Аще его (Владимира Игоревича) опутаевѣ красною
> дѣвицею, ни нама будетъ сокольца, ни нама красны дѣвице, то почнутъ
> наю птици бити въ полѣ Половецкомъ.